# PhoneGap + IFrame

Tags: html, apache-cordova, iframe

Estou querendo começar a usar o PhoneGap e queria saber se tem como usar um IFrame dentro do APP para abrir uma pagina web.

Se alguém souber outra forma de fazer isso vai estar me ajudando, obrigado.

Comment: você quer usar uma *tag frame* ou quer usar *frames* igual no *meteor*?

Comment: É iframe para abrir conteúdo de outro site dentro do app

Comment: eu não tenho muita experiencia com PhoneGap, mas já tentei abrir uma página externa e nunca consegui. de uma olhada nesse **[LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212824/how-can-i-open-an-iframe-in-a-phonegap-cordova-app-running-on-ios)**, talvez ajude

Comment: Acabei de descobri sobre o inappbrowser

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Comment: se você encontrou a resposta para seu problema antes de outra pessoa responder, vc pode responder sua própria pergunta e depois de 2 dias marcá-la como respondida